# Symfony 4 Mock service in functional test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony4

I am testing a service which essentially is mostly serializing an object and sending it via a service to an external system.

If I create the typical unittest I would mock the response of the serializer and of the service, which contacts the external system. In fact there would be not much left to test except calling a bunch of setter Methods in my object.

The alternative would be using a KernelTestCase and creating a functional test, which would be fine except I don't want to contact the external system, but to use a mock only for this "external" service.

Is there any possibility to achieve this in Symfony 4?
Or is there another approach to this?

What I am doing now is the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Service;

use App\Service\MyClassService;
use App\Service\ExternalClient\ExternalClient;
use JMS\Serializer\Serializer;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyClassServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /** @var Serializer */
    private $serializer;

    /** @var ExternalClient */
    private $externalClient;

    /** @var RequestInterface */
    private $request;

    /** @var MyClassService */
    private $myClassService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->logger = $kernel->getContainer()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->serializer = $kernel->getContainer()->get(SerializerInterface::class);
        $this->externalClient = $this->createMock(ExternalClient::class);
    }

    public function testPassRegistrationData()
    {
        $getParams = [
            'amount'          => '21.56',
            'product_id'      => 867,
            'order_id'        => '47t34g',
            'order_item_id'   => 2,
            'email'           => 'kiki%40bubu.com',
        ];

        $this->generateMyClassService($getParams);

        $userInformation = $this->myClassService->passRegistrationData();
        var_dump($userInformation);
    }

    /**
    * generateMyClassService
    *
    * @param $getParams
    *
    * @return MyClass
    */
    private function generateMyClassService($getParams)
    {
        $this->request = new Request($getParams, [],  [], [], [], [], null);

        $this->myClassService = new MyClassService(
            $this->logger,
            $this->serializer,
            $this->externalClient,
            $this->request
        );
    }
}
```

Give back this error:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot autowire service "App\Service\MyClassConfirmationService": argument "$request" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" but no such service exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't inject `Request` into your services. You should use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack` instead of `Request`. Also, you should check if `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()` doesn't return `null`. I suppose you get such error in process of container's initialization but you execute just a script (test) and of course, you don't have `Request` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole thing needed some more tweak here I post my solution to which Nikita's answer lead me:

As he suggested I replaced "request in my service with RequestStack which worked out fine:

```php
/**
 * @param LoggerInterface     $logger
 * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
 * @param ExternalClient      $externalClient
 * @param RequestStack        $requestStack
 */
public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    SerializerInterface $serializer,
    ExternalClient $externalClient,
    RequestStack $requestStack
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
    $this->externalClient = $externalClient;
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->params = $this->request->query;
}
```

In my test I faked the request like this:

```php
$this->request = new Request($getParams, [], [], [], [], [], null);

$this->requestStack = new RequestStack();
$this->requestStack->push($this->request);
```

However with that having fixed my next problems arised, since my class also asks for the logger and the serializer. 
For the Logger I used a general Loggerclass I created especially for this test situations. But that leaves me to get the serializer and I wanted the real one or else I could have stuck to a mostly useless UnitTest.

That is what I did:

```php
public function setUp()
{
    $kernel = self::bootKernel(); 
    $container = self::$container;
    $this->serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer.serializer');
}
```

This then gave me the real serializer from the container.
Now I can let my mocked external client give me mocked answers and I can test my service for reaction without bothering an external service.

Comment: BTW about logger. I always use monolog, in my tests I mock it like that: `$this->createMock(Logger::class)`

Comment: That is fine as long as you don't need to check in your tests if an log message of a certain level was written.